OpenCL how to wait for device side queue to finish before reading result from host
This is my simplified program structure :
// I call one main kernel from host side
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, main_kernel, 1, NULL, globalSize_g, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);

// Then on device side this kernel goes like this :

__kernel void main_kernel(...
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000...
    {
        enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), CLK_ENQUEUE_FLAGS_NO_WAIT, ...
        .
        .
        .
        enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), CLK_ENQUEUE_FLAGS_NO_WAIT, ...
    }
}

//Then back on host side I read the result from a buffer 

clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, ...);

Basically I have a kernel that then queues a bunch of other kernels on device side in a loop, each of these device side kernels need to wait for the previous kernel to finish. The for loop obviously finishes long before all the device side kernels do.
My problem is that when I read back the result not all of the device side kernels have finished executing so the results are incomplete. My question is how can I make sure everything in the device side queue has finished before reading back buffers on host side ?
I tried to call clFinish for both my host side queue and device side queue before I read the result back but this doesn't seem do to solve my problem.
I tried setting up an event and waiting for it like this but this doesn't work either because I am assuming this just waits for the main kernel to finish and not for the device side kernels as well.
cl_event event1;
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, main_kernel, 1, NULL, globalSize_g, 0, 0, NULL, &event1);
clWaitForEvents(1, &event1);

I thought maybe there is something I can call from device side but I couldn't find such thing in the OpenCL specification for this purpose specifically but maybe I missed it.
I thought about putting a while loop outside the for loop which checks some global variable that gets updated by the last kernel in the loop and when that variable reaches the number of iterations it's supposed to go through I break out of the while loop. This seems quite stupid and I am sure there is a proper way to do this.

@JanezKuhar This would defeat the purpose for doing this in the first place, I had all of these kernels being launched from host side initially but it's a lot of overhead, thousands of kernels calls. I am not trying to do a global synchronization, just want to figure out how to wait for all device side kernels to finish, same way you can do on host side, I am sure there is way, it's simply a queue after all.

I'm sorry, I've misunderstood the problem entirely! What issues are you facing with the last approach (where you wait for an event)? According to spec, that's the correct way: "a parent will not indicate that it is complete by setting its event to CL_COMPLETE until all child kernels have ended execution and have signaled completion by setting any associated events to the value CL_COMPLETE."

@JanezKuhar Even if I wait for the event it's still clearly not waiting for all child kernels to finish executing for some reason. I can confirm this is the case because I set up printf statements in every child kernel to see how far they get into the queue, so for instance whether my for loop has 100 or 1000 iterations, the printf statements always end on iteration 77, which I suspect is around the time the for loop finishes.

I suspect the way I am waiting for kernels to finish during each for loop might be causing this because I am using the same events and they're probably getting jumbled around from previous loops. I'll try to use an enqueue_marker at the end of every loop because it seems that this acts as barrier of sorts while waiting for events to finish.

After some more debugging it seems that at some point the child kernels start to not return CL_COMPLETE for some reason, though this error does not propagate to my parent kernel, I think I am hitting some weird limit on the number of items that can be queued. Moreover this seems to be related to my host side queue filling up somehow, not the device side one, I found that if I reinitialize the queue in between a number of kernel calls from host side this gets fixed, very bizarre. I am sure I am doing something wrong but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

I found out what's wrong, apparently there is indeed a limit to the amount of kernels that can be queued on device which is given by CL_DEVICE_MAX_ON_DEVICE_EVENTS, this seems to be 1024 on my device, why is it so  small beats me as it makes this feature quite useless. This still doesn't explain why clFinish or clFlush doesn't empty the queue in between kernel calls even if I don't hit it's limit but at least I figured out why this doesn't work.
Fortunately I can still break down the computation in a lot less host side kernel calls, so I can still benefit from the speedup somewhat.
